# Raspberry Pi - JavaScript doesn't work in chromium kiosk mode

Tags: javascript, chromium, raspberry-pi

I am running the latest Raspbian Wheezy O/S on my RPI and I am having a pretty strange problem.

I created a number of html files which I am trying to run automatically in kiosk mode on startup (modifying the autostart file).

```
@chromium --kiosk --incognito http://some.web.
```

Basically the HTML pages shuffle using the javascript setTimeout command:

```
setTimeout("location.href = 'widgets.html';", 120000);
```

Every HTML file has this command.

These commands work fine when I let the system boot up manually and launch the HTML files manually by double clicking on them. When they are executed by modifying autostart or run via command line, the above line doesn't work.

Any idea as to why this is happening?

I've tried playing around with the different chromium switches with no luck.

Comment: Kiosk mode might not let you do that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother with Chromium's kiosk mode, I think it's being dropped in newer versions. Try using the app command line switch instead.

```
chromium-browser --app=http://some.web
```

Secondly, if you're creating a web-based kiosk, check out the blog post that really helped me: http://www.alandmoore.com/blog/2011/11/05/creating-a-kiosk-with-linux-and-x11-2011-edition/